# GUI box handler java game

Tags: java, user-interface

SO, I am making a game in java and I have the basics done, now I am working on the GUI. What I was thinking of doing was making a GUI class that holds all of the arraylists. Then I want to create a new class for all of the different types of GUIs, GUIbox, GUIstats, stuff like that. I am really having troubles with putting this into code,all I have so far is the code below:

GUI class:

```
public class GUI {
ArrayList<GUIbox> guiBoxes = new ArrayList<GUIbox>();

public GUI() { }

public GUIbox getBoxByID(int id) {
    for(int i=0; i<guiBoxes.size(); i++) {
        if(guiBoxes.get(i).getId() == id) {
        return guiBoxes.get(i);
        }
        }
    return null;

   }
}
```

And the GUI box class (32 by 32 sized box that needs an x and y, an id, and the id of the item inside the box):

```
public class GUIbox {

protected float x, y;
protected int itemID;
private int id;



    public GUIbox(int id, float x, float y, int itemID) {
    this.id = id;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.itemID = itemID;
    }

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

So, what would be the most productive way to do this? In the end all I want to have to do is initiate the box GUIbox box1 = new GUIbox(boxId, x, y, itemID). And I want to be able to change what is in the box with something like changeContents(boxID, itemID). Maybe even a method to see what itemID is in what box.

Any help is appreciated, thank you. :)

Comment: Separate your view from it's data, allow the view to represent the data graphically. Provide functionality around the data to allow it to be modified, updated and accessed as well as providing notification of state changes should it be required.  Provide some kind of controller to allow the view to make modifications to the model and visa-versa. Take a look at [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: Also, if possible, defining a base "GUIObject" class or interface from which all you other "GUIxxx" classes extend from, it will make the management easier

Comment: If you could give me an example of this with code it would help me greatly, for I am not extremely fluent in java. :)